# Calling sqlcmd from Azure DevOps powershell task Fails

Tags: powershell, t-sql, azure-devops

I'm having an issue with the Powershell task of Azure Devops.

If I run this from the a command window in my build server; it will work
sqlcmd -S tcp:$(servername).database.windows.net -U $(login) -P $(password) -d $(dbname) -i $(sqlfile) -o $(outputfile)

but if I call that from an azure powershell task using Invoke-SqlCmd it fails with this error:
"The term 'Disable-AzContextAutosave' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, ..."

Comment: What else is in your workflow before the Invoke-SqlCmd? That is a PowerShell cmdlet that is providing the error - not a T-SQL command. This must be coming from a different part of your Devops pipeline.

Comment: I am fairly sure it is coming from there based on the logs. Right now testing if I have found the answer from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps 

I appears that the -o in sqlcmd is outputfile when on command line but Out-File -FilePath when called from powershell. *fingerscrossed

Answer (score 0):

You may try to [Update Azure PowerShell modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdIM4.jpg) to see whether it helps you. In addition, you can use Azure SQL Database Deployment task in Azure Pipeline, there are SQL Script File and Inline SQL Script types.

[image]

Comment: How's your issue going?